# DIV layer popup that just work on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html, layer

I made a hidden DIV in HTML file.
I want to make if i access this HTML with IE,
the Hidden DIV turn to visible with javascript.

Help me.

Comment: The simplest way is conditional comments. `<!--[if IE]><div>You are using Microsoft Internet Explorer.</div><![endif]-->`... However detecting the browser specifically is rarely the right solution and is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @Ariane I'm assuming the OP wants to show a message that says the site can't be used with IE, which violates graceful degradation, but is a legitimate use case when you know who your audience is and can dictate what browser they should use (eg. some internal web apps *only* work with IE).

Comment: @Asad Makes sense. Well, I did say "rarely".

Answer (score 1):

You could use IE conditional comments. I'm using inline style sheets here, but assuming you have a lot of CSS you could also put it in separate files and use `link`:

```
<style>
    #mydiv{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<!--[if IE]>
    <style>
        #mydiv{
            display:block !important;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Also note that if you're *absolutely certain* that you're declaring the conditional stylesheet after the one that specifies the `display:none` rule, you don't need the `!important` modifier.